# Relationship mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm have two schemas where one depends of the other to save.

```
const OrderSchema = new moongose.Schema({
    product: {
        type: moongose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1,
    },
    total_price: {
        type: Number,
    }
})

OrderSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    this.total_price = product.price * quantity

    next()
})

const Order = moongose.model('Order', OrderSchema)
```

And the other:

```
const ProductSchema = new moongose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    photo: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
})

const Product = moongose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

But when I try save one Order with one Product exiting in data base:

```
{
    "product":"5cae6ff5d478882ed8725911",
    "quantity":3
}
```

Show error: Error: ReferenceError: product is not defined

This is my controller to save a new Order:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const order = await Order.create(req.body)

        return res.send({ order })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
    idproduct: {
         type: moongose.Schema.ObjectId,
         required: true
     },
```

This way the post works correctly

Comment: No, don't have reference.

Answer (score 0):

LOL, I found the ERROR:

```
OrderSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    this.total_price = product.price * quantity

    next()
})
```

I forgot to use 'THIS', correct:

```
OrderSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    this.total_price = this.product.price * this.quantity

    next()
})
```

Hehehe, sorry guys...